# C# Emgu CV Trouble Predicting Face EigenFaceRecognizer

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to save face images and predict them using [Emgu CV 4.4](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv) with [EigenFaceRecognizer](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.4.0/document/html/62795d93-e4b8-3c3a-f11f-42ce97895c0e.htm) using `.Net5`.

 Basically I am getting a single image, resizing it (I read somewhere that smaller images have better accuracy),
adding it to the `List<Mat>`and saving the trained data to see what is there out of curiosity.
After that I'm using the same image and attempt to predict what it is (label).

Unfortunately it fails producing this error.
`Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: Wrong shapes for given matrices. Was size(src) = (1,57600), size(W) = (19200,1).'`

I also tried `imageForTraining.Mat` within `Predict` however the same error occurred.

```
// Get The GrayImage And Resize It.
Image<Bgr, byte> imageForTraining = grayImage.Resize(128, 150, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);
                    
// Create New cv::Mat Lists.
List<Mat> mats = new List<Mat>()
{
    imageForTraining.Mat
};
                    
// Dirty Solution For Label Testing.
List<int> labels = new List<int>()
{
    0
};

// Create Face Recognizer And Tell It There Is Only 1 Item.
FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(1);

// Write Data To File To See If Something Is There.
faceRecognizer.Write("trainingData");

// Attempt To Train.
faceRecognizer.Train(new VectorOfMat(mats.ToArray()), new VectorOfInt(labels.ToArray()));

// Test Image That Was Just Trained.
FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult predictionResult = faceRecognizer.Predict(imageForTraining);
```

Comment: `Was size(src) = (1,57600), size(W) = (19200,1).'` Did you perhaps get the dimensions the wrong way around?

Comment: I dont believe so as if I resize the image after its already been used for training, I receive this error `Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 76800 elements, but got 20000.'`
`

Comment: `(I read somewhere that smaller images have better accuracy)` Does it work if you _don't_ resize it?

Comment: not resizing `imageForTraining` results in the same error.